# How do I define a function that accepts any Task producing an IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await

I'm looking to create a function that accepts any task that produces an `IEnumerable<T>`.  To illustrate, consider the following function signature.

```
void DoWork<TElement>(Task<IEnumerable<TElement>> task)
{ }
```

Now, I would like to call this method as follows:

```
Task<int[]> task = Task.FromResult(new[] { 1, 2, 3 });
DoWork(task);
```

Clearly, this doesn't work since the two `Task` types are not the same, and that covariance doesn't exist for Tasks.  However, I am wondering if there are some clever tricks that will allow this to work, inspired by the following example.

```
async Task<IEnumerable<int>> GetTask()
{
    return await Task.FromResult(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
}
```

Here, `await` is effectively creating a new task with the result of the inline task, hence the illusion of a type conversion.

To give a more detailed example, I'd like to allow for users to call `DoWork` without too much of a burden in conversions:

```
// Service proxy method
Task<int[]> GetInts()
{
    // simplified for brevity
    return Task.FromResult(new[] { 1, 2, 3 });
}

// Service proxy method
Task<long[]> GetLongs()
{
    // simplified for brevity
    return Task.FromResult(new[] { 100L, 200L, 300L });
}

async Task<IEnumerable<T>> DoWork<T>(Func<Task<IEnumerable<T>>> getData,
                                     Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    return (await getData()).Where(predicate);
}

// GOAL:
DoWork(GetInts, i => i % 2 == 0);
DoWork(GetLongs, l => l % 40 == 0);
```

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate question.  I understand that `Task<>` is not covariant; I'm asking if there is a clever syntax or declarations that will accomplish what covariance would otherwise do.

Comment: Like, say, `dynamic`?

Comment: I suspect `dynamic` will indeed make all the type matching problems go away, but I was hoping to find a statically typed solution first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could introduce one more Type parameter and do something like this:

```
async Task<IEnumerable<TElement>> DoWork<T, TElement>(Func<Task<T>> getData,
                              Func<TElement, bool> predicate) where T : IEnumerable<TElement>
{
    return (await getData()).Where(predicate);
}

Task<int[]> GetInts()
{
    return Task.Run(() => new[] { 1, 2, 3 });
}

Task<long[]> GetLongs()
{
    return Task.Run(() => new[] { 100L, 200L, 300L });
}
```

Then you could to

```
static void Main()
{
    var ints = DoWork<int[], int>(GetInts, i => i % 2 == 0).Result;
    var longs = DoWork<long[], long>(GetLongs, i => i % 2 == 0).Result;
}
```

Or as noted by OP in comments you can make compiler to infer the types if you specify `TElement` explicitly.

```
var ints = DoWork(GetInts, (int i) => i % 2 == 0).Result;
```

Your code doesn't work since `Task<T>` is not "Covariant" on `T`. You may be aware that classes can't be covariant.

Comment: This is a very promising technique.  You can also omit the explicit generic arguments from the call, if you declare i as `int` (or `long`) in the lambda. For instance: `DoWork(GetInts, (int i) => i % 2 == 0)`.

Comment: @SteveGuidi Cool, I was trying to push the load on compiler to infer the types but failed. Forgot about this. Thanks..